# Two phone numbers (one USA, one Qatari) same phone, calls and text over cell data. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, calls, dual-sim

I need your advice and ideas. I am moving to Qatar in a couple days for work and I am trying to figure out the best cellphone situation. Currently I have a Google Nexus 5 which is fabulous, on AT&T which is less than fabulous (but that is beside the point).

My goal is to have my Nexus 5 with a US phone number (doesn't need to be the same one I currently have) that my friends here can call and text me on, and a Qatari number that my coworkers can call and text me on.

Here is where I am at:

- Ruled out AT&T completely because their international plans are absurd.
- Getting a Vodafone or Oreedo sim and using it my Nexus 5 (this wouldn't have any way for US friends to cheaply call/text though, so I don't think it is the best option)
- Going with a t-mobile sim (they have unlimited data and text in Qatar). I would need some way to have two numbers (one US, one Qatari) that could make calls and send texts over cell data. Google voice is one option but I think it only supports one number.

Anyways, any advice would be appreciated. I have thought about this a lot and done some research but I can't find a way to easily and cheaply do it.

Also, if this question could be better answered or belongs on a different stackexchange site, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Android supports VOIP built in. You could get a US # from someone like callcentric.